# Cache a Db-Resultset - Best practice? (Application, not ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, caching

ASP.NET have a nice caching feature, how do I best apply same logic to this scenario? This is a background application - not a web-something. I want to get and return the cached object from memory, instead of repeating requests from database. Only the first request per each unique match of the parameters `c`, `a` and `cu` should invoke the database. Let say, per 6 hours.

The constructor take three parameters and serves as a setter for three lists. The  constructor recieves a neat collection of 0-300 strictly choosen rows of data. Though, with  a tensing amount of requests.

(Please note that the sample and namings are pseudo)

```
/// <summary>
/// Constructor 
/// </summary>
public Collect(string c, string a, string cu) 
    : base(c, a, cu)
{

    db = new DatabaseInstance();

    // DObject
    this._d  = (from d in db.DObject
                        where ....
                     select d).ToList();

    // SObject  
    this._s  = (from s in db.SObject
                    where ......
                    select s).ToList();

    // MObject
    this._v = (from mv in db.MObject
                     where ......
                     select mv).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` object for that.  It works almost the same way as `System.Web.Caching` works but is available without references to `System.Web` and is a lot more extendable.

Comment: Probably, that was the point. Sorry. It was easy enough for Googling. I was confused at first because everything I got was related to web caching and heavy alternated samples (like for Enterprise-level  frameworks). Memorycache did it!